# mysql linking 4 tables and some conditions

Tags: mysql

I tried to relate these 4 tables, but I keep running into problems. Does any one have any idea why?

```
Part (
  part_num,
  description,
  on_hand
)

Order (
  order_num,
  date,
  customer_id
)

Order_line (
  part_num,
  order_num,
  price
)

Customer (
  customer_ID,
  customer_name
)
```

I'm trying to fetch the `order_num` and `date` for `customer` with name `"raymond"` and description `"stove"`.

```
SELECT order.order_num, date
FROM order, part, order_line, customer
WHERE order.order_num = order_line.order_num
      AND part.part_num = order_line.part_num
      AND order.customer_id = customer.customer_id
      AND customer_name = 'raymond' 
      AND description = 'stove' ;
```

I hit enter and this appeared: `,>` instead of the `->`

Comment: What are you getting instead? Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Im not getting anything. it wont run . when I hit enter the symbol I normally get from mysql - > became ,>

Comment: That will happen if you type unbalanced quotes. I don't see it in the query you posted, you must have mistyped something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to selecet `part.part_num` as follows also escaping the `order` it is a keyword:

```
Select part.part_num,date
from `order`, part, order_line, customer
where `order`.order_num = order_line.order_num
and part.part_num = order_line.part_num
and `order`.customer_id = customer.customer_id
and customer_name = 'raymond' 
and description = 'stove' ;
```

Comment: sorry I meant to say order_num , date is what I needed.

Comment: oh ok then try escaping the `order` table as it is a MySQL keyword.

Comment: same thing. it wouldnt run. normally in mysql I have this symbol -> everytime I hit enter , then whether it works or a error message appear. but when I do this problem the symbol changed to ' > and it is very hard to get out of this.

Comment: are you running your queries from the MySQL cmd line?

Comment: I think so. I am new at this.

Comment: Please exit the MySQL command and start it again? What Os are you running?